# Abnormal behavior of Select in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a primitive Vue widget, which consists of two pages. In each page you can select dummy options from dropdown (which change `value1` and `value2` variables accordingly)

The problem is when I move from "stepOne" to "stepTwo", for some reason the value of `value2` becomes `undefined` unexpectedly (even though there is no logical connection between `value1` and `value2`, nor `step` variable).

Ideally, after the first step, in second step it should automatically select "option 1", as the value equals to `value2=1`

I wonder why `undefined` is assigned to `value2`, and how can I prevent the given behavior

Here is my sample code, that contains this weird behavior:

```html
<div>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-if="step === steps.stepOne">
            <p>This is step One</p>
            <select v-model="value1">
                <option v-for="item in array1" :value="item.value">{{ item.name }}</option>
            </select>
            <button @click="changeStep()">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div v-if="step === steps.stepTwo">
            <p>This is step Two</p>
            <select v-model="value2">
                <option value="2">option 2</option>
                <option value="0">option 0</option>
                <option value="1">option 1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        value1: {{value1}}
        <br>
        value2: {{value2}}
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script>
    var steps = {
        stepOne: 1,
        stepTwo: 2,
    };

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            step: steps.stepOne,

            value1: 'b',
            value2: 1,

            array1: [
                {
                    name: 'option a',
                    value: 'a',
                },
                {
                    name: 'option b',
                    value: 'b',
                },
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            changeStep() {
                this.step = steps.stepTwo;
            }
        },
        watch: {
            value1: function(newValue) {
                console.log("value1: "  + newValue);
            },
            value2: function(newValue) {
                console.log("value2: "  + newValue);
            }
        },
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about how vue.js works, but I've tried putting a `:` before the value attribute and it started working!

```html
<div>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-if="step === steps.stepOne">
            <p>This is step One</p>
            <select v-model="value1">
                <option v-for="item in array1" :value="item.value">{{ item.name }}</option>
            </select>
            <button @click="changeStep()">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div v-if="step === steps.stepTwo">
            <p>This is step Two</p>
            <select v-model="value2">
                <option :value="2">option 2</option>
                <option :value="0">option 0</option>
                <option :value="1">option 1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        value1: {{value1}}
        <br>
        value2: {{value2}}
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script>
    var steps = {
        stepOne: 1,
        stepTwo: 2,
    };

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            step: steps.stepOne,

            value1: 'b',
            value2: 1,

            array1: [
                {
                    name: 'option a',
                    value: 'a',
                },
                {
                    name: 'option b',
                    value: 'b',
                },
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            changeStep() {
                this.step = steps.stepTwo;
            }
        },
        watch: {
            value1: function(newValue) {
                console.log("value1: "  + newValue);
            },
            value2: function(newValue) {
                console.log("value2: "  + newValue);
            }
        },
    });
</script>
```